# Unable to import mail module in Python

Tags: python, logging

I trying to import the `logging` module but I get this error:

```
./mail.py: line 1: import: command not found from: can't read /var/mail/marrow.mailer 
./mail.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `level=logging.INFO 
./mail.py: line 3: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: No. Not without seeing what you actually want help. Post your actual code, at least line 3.

Answer (score 3):

You'e most likely missing a "shebang line" in your script: it's being interpreted as a shell script, and not a Python script (hence the shell errors).

You need to tell your terminal which interpreter to use when you do `./mail.py` (Python).

To do so, add this on the first line of `mail.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: ./mail.py: line 1: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/marrow.mailer
./mail.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `level=logging.INFO'
'/mail.py: line 3: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
➜  iris git:(master) ✗ ./mail.py
env: python\r: No such file or directory
It is not working ><!!!! Thank you help

Comment: @Smallbo Replace `/usr/bin/env python` with the output of `which python` then.